# What's the definition of a mouse in Mitchell's handbook article "the covering lemma"?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, soft-question, inner-model-theory

In the book "handbook of set theory", in the chapter "the covering lemma", definition 3.24, Mitchell defines what is mouse.

However he did not give any definition of $\mathcal{U}_\gamma$ and $\mathcal{U}\restriction \gamma$, before he uses them. What is his definition regarding these notations?

Comment: $\upharpoonright$ usually denotes codomain restriction for functions, but I’m not sure about the other.

Comment: @AlecRhea In my experience, $\upharpoonright$ is most often used for domain restriction, not codomain restriction. But more generally, it is often used for restriction of any kind.

Comment: Perhaps the op is actually asking about $\mathcal{U}$?

Comment: I guess it is implicit that $\mathcal U$ is a sequence of objects indexed by ordinals.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg I also guess this, but he didn't give any definition about $\mathcal{U}$...

Comment: The kind of thing that $\mathcal{U}_\gamma$ is, is discussed in 3.24.1.(a),(b)... Are you looking at that?

Comment: (However, I think there is a condition missing. There would usually be the requirement that if $\mathcal{U}_\gamma\neq\emptyset$ then $\gamma=\kappa^{++\mathrm{Ult}(J_\gamma[\mathcal{U}],\mathcal{U}_\gamma)}$, whereas in 3.24 it just seems to say that $\gamma=\kappa^{++J_\gamma[\mathcal{U}]}$. Of course the latter literally means that $J_\gamma[\mathcal{U}]\models$"$\kappa^+$ is the largest cardinal".)

Comment: Have you checked the Chapter "Beginning Inner Model Theory" also written by Mitchell?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Ah, I suppose in accordance with the notation $f:X\to Y$ for a function I’ve been using $\upharpoonleft$ for domain restriction and $\upharpoonright$ for codomain restriction, so the little harpoon hook points to the side being restricted.

Comment: That makes sense, but I haven't seen that distinction before, whereas I do often see $f\upharpoonright A$ for the domain restriction case $A\subseteq X$.

Comment: @FarmerS In 3.24 the author did noticed the $\mathcal{U}_\gamma$ predicate. However, in "inner models and large cardinals", definition 4.1(b), the index of the measure is required to be $\kappa^{+}$, not $\kappa^{++}$. Why there is such a difference?

Comment: Using $\kappa^{++}$ is more generalizable than is $\kappa^+$. For example for models $M$ with two distinct total normal measures $E,F$ with the same critical point $\kappa$, we would need to set them to be $\mathcal{U}_\gamma$ and $\mathcal{U}_\delta$ for some distinct ordinals $\gamma,\delta$. So we couldn't use $\gamma=\kappa^{+M}=\delta$. A very natural indexing is to instead use $\gamma=\kappa^{++\mathrm{Ult}(M,E)}$ and $\delta=\kappa^{++\mathrm{Ult}(M,F)}$. This also generalizes well to models with extenders, not just measures, on their sequence, indexing with...

Comment: $\gamma=(\nu^+)^{\mathrm{Ult}(M|\gamma,E)}$ where $\nu$ is the "natural length" of $E$; the natural length is the least ordinal $\geq(\kappa^{+})^{M|\gamma}$ which contains all the generators of $E$, where $\kappa$ is the critical point of $E$. This is Mitchell-Steel indexing. Another natural alternative is $\lambda$-indexing, where $\gamma=(\lambda^{+})^{\mathrm{Ult}(M|\gamma,E)}$ where $\lambda$ is the image of $\kappa$ under the $E$-ultrapower embedding.

Comment: @FarmerS Thank you for your good explanation. It's painful that the definition of mouse is always changing. Does it have an official version now?